# List (top-level) declared variables in a Windows Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, reflection, system.reflection

I can easily list all controls in a Form, after creating an instance of it.

Is there any mechanism to list all ***declared variables*** or such objects?
Perhaps I shall call it *declarations*. Only top-level declarations are enough.

Let's assume we have `MyForm` Form with such top-level declarations:

```
Dim Town as String
Dim ZIP as String
Dim StreetName as String
Dim StreetNo as String
Public dtCountries as DataTable
Public LstCities as List(Of String)
...
```

Pseudo-code example:

```
Dim MyForm as New MyForm          ' create instance of the form
Dim dtVariables as New Datatable  ' create a datatable to store found objects
dtVariables.Columns.Add("ID", GetTy(Int32))
dtVariables.Columns.Add("VariableName", GetTy(String))
dtVariables.Columns.Add("VariableType", GetTy(String))

For Each Varbl In MyForm.***variables***   ' <<< (how) to read all variables
    Dim nr as Datarow = dtVariables.NewRow
    nr("ID") = dtVariables.Rows.Count + 1
    nr("VariableName") = Varbl.Name
    nr("VariableType") = Varbl.GetType.ToString.Replace("System.Windows.Forms.", "")
    dtVariables.Rows.Add(nr)       ' add found object/variable to our datatable
Next
```

The result I am looking for is something like:

```
 1   Town         String
 2   ZIP          String
 3   StreetName   String
 4   StreetNo     Int32
 5   dtCountries  DataTable
 6   LstCities    List(Of String)
 ... ...          ...
```

I know that I can read `MyForm.designer.vb` file and look there for declarations.
This question is about getting it from an object model of a Form / instance of a Form.

Comment: You can look into Reflection and, in particular, the `Type.GetFields` method.

Comment: Thank you @jmcihinney, that sounds like a good starting point.

Comment: You can use `GetType(class)` To get types declared in the class.

Comment: @preciousbetine GetType returns the type of the class.`Dim t = GetType(Foo)` will return `t.Name = "Foo" ` It does not return the what is in the class. The name of the Function is singular which is a good clue that it will return a single value.

Comment: Actually, `GetType(Foo)` is a Visual Basic operator and not part of reflection. `Type.GetType()` is the better way. There is also `Object.GetType `which can return the type of an instance of a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example using a filtered collection of [FieldInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo) objects returned by [`Type.GetType().GetFields()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields)

Since you want this method to return both Public and non-Public Fields, the collection must be filtered because, since this is a Form class, it will include all the controls a Form contains.
The collection of `FieldInfo` is then filtered using `FieldType.Namespace`, where the **`Namespace`** is not **`System.Windows.Forms`**.

The [BindingFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags) are set to `Instance | Public | NonPublic | DeclaredOnly`.

When the Field represents a Collection (List, Dictionary etc.), the [Type.GenericTypeArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.generictypearguments) property needs to be parsed to extract the arguments Collection.

I'm using a couple of helper functions to *clean up* the Fields Name and to retrieve the collection of arguments as a formatted string.

Using the sample Fields you posted (I added a Dictionary to test the output):

```
Dim Town As String
Dim ZIP As String
Dim StreetName As String
Dim StreetNo As String
Public dtCountries As DataTable
Public LstCities As List(Of String)
Public DictOfControls As Dictionary(Of String, Control)
```

this is the result:

[image: Class GetType GetFields]

```
Dim ClassFields As New DataTable
ClassFields.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
ClassFields.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
ClassFields.Columns.Add("FieldType", GetType(String))

Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or
             BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly

Dim allFields As List(Of FieldInfo) =
    Me.GetType().GetFields(flags).
        Where(Function(f) (Not (f.FieldType.Namespace.Equals("System.Windows.Forms"))) AndAlso f.Name <> "components").
        ToList()

For Each field As FieldInfo In allFields
    Dim dr As DataRow = ClassFields.NewRow
    dr("ID") = ClassFields.Rows.Count + 1
    dr("Name") = field.Name
    dr("FieldType") = GetFieldTypeName(field.FieldType.Name) &
                      GetTypeArguments(field.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments)
    ClassFields.Rows.Add(dr)
Next

Private Function GetFieldTypeName(field As String) As String
    Dim EndPosition As Integer = field.IndexOf(ChrW(96))
    Return If(EndPosition > 0, field.Substring(0, EndPosition), field)
End Function

Private Function GetTypeArguments(args As Type()) As String
    If args.Length = 0 Then Return String.Empty
    Return $" ({String.Join(", ", args.Select(Function(arg) arg.Name))})"
End Function
```

If [Interpolated String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) is not available (before VB.Net version 14), use a [Composite Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#composite-format-string) string:

```
Return $" ({String.Join(", ", args.Select(Function(arg) arg.Name))})"
```

can be expressed as:

```
Return String.Format(" ({0})", String.Join(", ", args.Select(Function(arg) arg.Name)))
```

Comment: Does this show variables declared in methods or just the top level variables?

Comment: @preciousbetine  Well, this is using `GetFields()`, so just Fields. Local variables are not Fields.

Comment: Brilliant and educative! Tested, works as a charm. I just replaced Me.GetType.GetFields(flags)... for MyForm.GetType.GetFields... and got the desired result!

Comment: Excellent! Saved to my SO word doc under Reflection and my Code Repository. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I've not had the time to test this since yesterday, but I just did that now and it works perfectly except the second to the last line . It throws an error `"$ is not defined"`

Comment: @preciousbetine  [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) => *This feature is available in Visual Basic 14 and later versions.*

Comment: @preciousbetine  See the edit (at the bottom of the post).

Comment: Wow, looks like I have to upgrade my vB compiler.I still use VS 2013 cause I have the ultimate version of it. Planning to get VS 2019.Anyway, thanks.It's working now. Wish I could vote more than once on an answer;-)